# HTTP Status 404. Do not show data after turning the page

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I import projects from http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2014/03/building-java-web-application-using-hibernate-with-spring.html
I was trying to figure out the cause but still do not know why it does not display the page register after I click the register button. It does not show any errors in the console. The project uses Spring and Hibernate to write web login and register.

Controller.java

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes("student")
public class StudentController {

    @Autowired
    private StudentService studentService;

    @RequestMapping(value="/signup", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String signup(Model model) {
        Student student = new Student();        
        model.addAttribute("student", student);     
        return "signup";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/signup", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String signup(@Valid @ModelAttribute("student") Student student, BindingResult result, Model model) {        
        if(result.hasErrors()) {
            return "signup";
        } else if(studentService.findByUserName(student.getUserName())) {
            model.addAttribute("message", "User Name exists. Try another user name");
            return "signup";
        } else {
            studentService.save(student);
            model.addAttribute("message", "Saved student details");
            return "redirect:login.html";
        }
    }
```

index.jsp

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="signup.html">Signup» </a>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>studentHibernateServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/servletConfig.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>studentHibernateServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:/jpaContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
</web-app>
```

it's always the same as the picture below

[image]

Comment: Do you have signup.html page in your project? 404 error means that page not found.

Comment: I have sigup.jsp page, I think it will turn into sigup.html by    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>

Answer (score 1):

The `<servlet-mapping>` with `<url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>` simply directs all requests that end in "html" to your studentHibernateServlet. It will not translate *.jsp into *.html.

You are going to need to add a view resolver to your web.xml to map request to views. If your signup.jsp is saved to the WEB-INF folder you can use the below xml.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">     
  <property name="prefix">
    <value>/WEB-INF/</value>
  </property>
  <property name="suffix">
    <value>.jsp</value>
  </property>
</bean>
```

You may have to replace `<url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>` with `<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>` in order for the view name `"signup"` to be picked up by your servlet.

After those changes, your dispatcher servlet will handle the request for `"signup"` by appending the specified prefix and suffix i.e. `/WEB-INF/singup.jsp`, which can then be resolved to an actual view.